# Burninate the [named] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

Probably the [named](/questions/tagged/named) tag should be burninated. It's used in over 150 questions for a wide variety of topics. Among them:

- named pipes
- named parameters
- named entities
- named ranges
- named functions

and a lot of stuff about various naming issues.

I don't know if there are really meaningful uses for such tag, but it seems to me that our dear Trogdor should be called on it.

Comment: Don't forget `named`, the executable associated [with BIND](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIND).

Comment: Got rid of most [named] [pipe(s)] and variants by retagging to [named-pipes]. The BIND ones I'm not sure about, but [named] might simply be removable on those that already have [bind]. And I guess there's not much harm in removing it from all other named thingies.